# how to match no following sibling

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

Here's my xml,

```
 <w:tc>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr></w:pPr>
      <w:r></w:r>
    </w:p>
 </w:tc>
 <w:tc>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr></w:pPr>
    </w:p>
 </w:tc>
```

I want to match w:p which is preceded by w:tc and has no following sibling w:r, Precisely i want second w:tc. Code what i  have tried,

```
  <xsl:template match="w:pPr[ancestor::w:p[ancestor::w:tc] and not(following-sibling::w:r)]">
```

I need xpath for w:pPr having no following-sibling

Comment: Actually the xpath i have posted is working perfect. The problem is when w:pPr is followed by w:hyperlink. Now i have ignored w:hyperlink too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem is when w:pPr is followed by w:hyperlink. Now i have ignored w:hyperlink too.

If you want to match a `w:pPr` that has no following sibling elements *at all* (regardless of name), then just use a `match` pattern of

```
w:pPr[ancestor::w:p[ancestor::w:tc] and not(following-sibling::*)]
```

or equivalently (and slightly shorter)

```
w:tc//w:p//w:pPr[not(following-sibling::*)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the XPath is simple and straightforward, you have to filter elements olny. Your filtring could be based on the content of the element (using `[]` and path inside the brackets). With the filtered elements you can work as same as with the XML tree (start filtering again or select the final elements).

In your case, first you have to choose the correct `tc` element (filter the element as you need):

- Based on the count of elements: `//tc[count(./p/*) = 1]`, or
- Based on non existing `r` element: `//tc[not(./p/r)]`, or
- Based on non existing `r` and `hyperlink` element: `//tc[not(./p/r) and not(./p/hyperlink)]`
- Based on existing `pPr` and non existing `r` (it is not a necessary because the `pPr` is filtred in second step): `//tc[./p/r and not(./p/r)]`

It returns the following XML.

```
<tc> 
  <p> 
    <pPr>pPr</pPr> 
  </p> 
</tc>
```

Then just simply say what do you want from the new XML:

- Do you want the `pPr` element? Use: `/p/pPr`

All together:

```
//tc[count(./p/*) = 1]/p/pPr
```

or

```
//tc[not(./p/r)]/p/pPr
```

**Note**: `//` means find the element anywhere in the document.

**Update 1**: Hyperlink condition added.